# Generar imagen en un frame con Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, imagen, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy intentando generar una imagen dentro de un frame que esta dentro de una clase pero no me genera la imagen a pesar de que el mismo label toma el tamaño de la imagen. He investigado pero ningún método luce como mi código.

Sé que usando este código si se genera sin problemas:

```
from tkinter import *

v=Tk()

f = Frame(v)

i = PhotoImage(file="pizza2.png")

l = Label(f, image=i)
l.pack()

f.pack()

v.mainloop()
```

El código con el que estoy trabajando actualmente es este:

```
from tkinter import *

#Clase que generará la ventana y manipulará los frames
class VentanaMF(Tk):
    #*args permite pasar tantas variables como deseen
    #*kwargs trabaja con variables para diccionarios
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) #Inicializa los elementos de tkitner

        #Ventana
        ventana = Frame(self) #contiene el frame para mostrar los componentes del programa
        ventana.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        ventana.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        ventana.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {} #Diccionario que manejara los frames del programa

        for Fr in (Inicio, MPrincipal):

            frame = Fr(ventana, self) #Funcion para el frame principal

            self.frames[Fr] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew") #posicionamiento del frame//los posicionamientos de sticky expanden el elemento en la dirección dada

        self.show_frame(Inicio)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        #Comandos para mostrar el frame
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()#Trae el frame al frente de todo

#Clase que contiene la presentación del programa
class Inicio(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        lp = Label(self, text="Texto cualquiera", font="times 12 bold")
        lp.pack(pady=10, padx=10) #Los pad modifican el tamaño de la etiqueta
        
        bmp = Button(self, text="Menú principal", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MPrincipal))
        bmp.pack()

#Clase para menú principal
class MPrincipal(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        ltitle = Label(self, text="Provincias")
        ltitle.place(x=100, y=20)
        ltitle.pack()

        #Imagen de prueba
        i = PhotoImage(file="pizza2.png")    
        
        li = Label(self, image=i, bg="black")
        li.place(x=100, y=100)
        li.pack()

        bbutton = Button(self, text="Presentación del grupo", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Inicio))
        bbutton.place(x=200, y=200)
        bbutton.pack()

        b1 = Button(self, text="Bocas del Toro", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PBdT))
        b1.place(x=10, y=10)

class PBdT(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        ltitle = Label(self, text="Ubicación 1")
        ltitle.place(x=100, y=20)

        bmp = Button(self, text="Menú principal", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MPrincipal))
        bmp.pack()

#Modulo principal
py=VentanaMF()
py.geometry("800x600")

py.mainloop()
```

Aún no manejo bien este lenguaje, por lo que el código está documentado para saber lo que ocurre. Además, cabe destacar que he intentado mostrar la imagen usando label y canvas pero ninguno me ha resultado, no se si estaré pasando algo por alto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se encuentra en la definición de `MPrincipal.__init__`:

```py
class MPrincipal(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        # ...

        i = PhotoImage(file="pizza2.png")            
        li = Label(self, image=i, bg="black")

        # ...
```

En lugar de almacenar la imagen en `i` utiliza `self.i`:

```py
self.i = PhotoImage(file="pizza2.png")            
li = Label(self, image=self.i, bg="black")
```

**La imagen debe ser accesible para el *widget padre* del *label***, y si la almacenas en una variable local del método, al finalizar la ejecución de dicho método la imágen deja de ser visible para el widget padre (cosas de Tcl/Tk).

Un saludo!